# SAS merging columns that differ

Tags: sas

I have two data sets that I would like to merge by cities. the problem is that one dataset just has the name for example: "Bently", "Caroline", etc. But the other data set has for example "Town of Bently", "Village of Caroline", etc. Is there anyway of merging them using substrings? any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You could use `index` function with `proc sql` like this:

```
data data_a;
input city $ x;
datalines;
London 1
York 4
Bukovica 10
Berlin 3
;
run;


data data_b;
input city $1-15 y;
datalines;
Good Old London 10
New York        40
Spisic Bukovica 100
;
run;


proc sql;
  create table merge as
  select a.city as city_a
        ,b.city as city_b
        ,x
        ,y
  from data_a as a
         inner join
       data_b as b
         on index(b.city, strip(a.city)) > 0 or index(a.city, strip(b.city)) > 0;
quit;
```

Just modify the join so it suits your needs (inner, left, right, full).

If you have city names that are not substrings of each other you could try calculating edit distance between two names with `complev` or `compged` and try to do some matching that way (maybe take the closest match or closest match above some limit).

Answer (score 1):

If in the second dataset the form is always "word + of + actual_name" then I would use a datastep with

```
city = scan(city_old,-1);
```

and then you can compare the two with a merge- or a proc sql-statement.

[Here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214639.htm) the link to the SAS-support for the scan function.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the index function.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212242.htm

> Searches a character expression for a string of characters, and
>   returns the position of the string's first character for the first
>   occurrence of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always '... of ', then you can use the position of "of" to guide you.  Scan (... -1) won't always work in the case of multiple-word cities ("New York City").

```
data test;
c1='Town of Bentley';
c1_of=find(c1,'of');
c2=substr(c1,c1_of+2);
put _all_;
run;
```